# Selenium webdriver , chrome browser, maven project, junit project

Tags: maven, google-chrome, selenium, junit, webdriver

I am executing a maven test project/ Junit project( its both keyword driven and data driven). Once it executes the quit keyword. The tab are opening automatically. I am using chrome browser. I tried to terminate the process in eclipse. but still the opening of chrome tabs with the same url keeps happening.could you help me with this?

Comment: What is code written in quit keyword?

Comment: driver.quit(); inside the block

Answer (score 0):

Are there more than one class in your maven test folder. 
If so "mvn test"command will execute all the classes one by one.
if you don't want to run the unwanted classes you could skipped the class.

Comment: i do have other classes, but those are required